# bootstrap carousel controls not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a very common question, I'll post links to other answers below.

A minimal sample: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/284188

**html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <center><p> First slide</p></center>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <center><p> Second slide</p></center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel()
})
```

This creates a bootstrap carousel, the animation works, the carousel automatically switches between first and second slide. But the controls don't do anything.

Here are similar SO posts:

- [Bootstrap Carousel Not Responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801002/bootstrap-carousel-not-responding) the problem was a broken link to jquery
- [Bootstrap Carousel controls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576626/bootstrap-carousel-controls-not-working) not properly calling carousel()
- [Bootstrap 4 Carousel controls not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820156/bootstrap-4-carousel-controls-not-working) popper.js is not properly included
- [bootstrap carousel controls is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619210/bootstrap-carousel-controls-is-not-working) jquery not included

I think that my setup is correct, I basically just pasted the carousel sample code into the bootstrap [starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit the fiddle, you'll notice that the code works now.
The reason is that carousel needs `id="carouselExampleControls"`.

With that id, everything is fine. If you remove it, it doesn't respond anymore.

The id is necessary, since the control items reference it:

```
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
      <body>

        <div id="carouselId" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselId" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselId" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: argh, I updated the fiddle.
The reason it didn't work was that the carousel is missing an id - which is not mentioned in docs. Adding that fixes the bug. I must have accidentally updated the code on the fiddle too.